# In listview,Viewstub cannot be found after the previous one is inflate

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater, viewstub

I am using some list item layout and in the item layout, there is a Viewstub where I want to put some image in.I don't have the source of list item layout and just know there are some TextViews and ViewStubs in it.

My purpose is to find the ViewStub first and set my personal layout and play with it. However, some of the ViewStub cannot be found.

```
public class TJAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    ....
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        View item = view;
        ViewStub contentstub = (ViewStub)item.findViewById(R.id.content_stub);

        if (contentstub == null){
            LOG.error("TJ,contentstub is null");
        } else  {
            LOG.error("TJ,contentstub is not null");
            contentstub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.icon_image);
            View iconImage = contentstub.inflate();
        }
        ....
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        bindView(view, context, cursor);
    }
}
```

And the log output is like this:

```
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is not null
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is null
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is not null
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is not null
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is null
 TJ,bindView is called
 TJ,contentstub is not null
```

I spent a lot of time on it and have no idea why this happens.

Can some body help?

=================================================================

As blahdiblah suggested, now I can find the iconImage. But I don't quite understand why the next item is affected and I cannot press the list item any more. It did not respond.

```
ImageButton iconImage = null;
ViewStub contentstub = (ViewStub)item.findViewById(R.id.content_stub);
if (contentstub == null){
    LOG.error("TJ,contentstub is null");
    iconImage = (ImageButton)item.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
} else  {
    LOG.error("TJ,contentstub is not null");
    contentstub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.list_item_icon_image);
    View image = contentstub.inflate();
    iconImage = (ImageButton)image.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

}

if (iconImage == null) {
    LOG.error("TJ,iconImage is null");
} else {
    LOG.error("TJ, iconImage is not null");
}
```

Comment: yeah,View item = view;I simplified the code

Comment: Does the `ViewStub` have an `android:inflatedId` set on it?

Comment: I don't have the xml file for the list item. But to my knowledge, no.

Comment: Right, you mentioned that.  Just out of curiosity, how is it that you can inflate a resource that you don't have the source of?

Comment: Someone else works on this part and they built a library that I can use. No body else has the same problem with me. And it is so tricky to me..

Comment: Huh.  Library projects often contain compiled java code, but resources are usually unchanged. I didn't realize it could be otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `contentstub.inflate();` the content of the ViewStub is replaced ***including its ID***.  When the view is recycled in another call to `bindView`, searching for `R.id.content_stub` will fail because the ViewStub was replaced by `R.layout.icon_image`.

The solution is to look for an ID you set in `layout/icon_image.xml` if the search for `R.id.content_stub` doesn't turn up anything.

Also, for what it's worth, you shouldn't have to manually call `bindView` in `newView`.  That should be taken care of automatically.

Comment: Yes!Now I can find the iconImage and it is not null!

Comment: But I don't quite understand why? Does it always affect the next one? Why only the next not all? And even if I do find the iconImage in my personal layout, is it still arrange as I want? I mean, if in this list view, I have six items and code in this way, does the image still correspond the item?

Comment: @T.J. The CursorAdapter docs appears to gloss over it, but ListViews reuse list item Views from items that are no longer visible to increase efficiency.  The [the docs on `convertView` in Adapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) touch on this.  So if you get a View in which the stub has already been inflated, it's one that you already added data to that scrolled off screen. If you don't to anything to it, it'll still show the old data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And the most important part is about bindView. Since I called it myself, so bindView is called twice! That's way the null/not null toggles!